# Use javascript to add a CSS class to all elements with another class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to use javascript to add a Class  to all elements with a different Class. I know you might think this is redundant but for the situation i am in it is needed. i need a way to look though all elements with that class name and add the class but I don't understand how to get a count?  I am working with a cms to where I cannot change the styling in the class it self.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var ClassBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("buttonSubmit");

            ClassBtn.className = ClassBtn.className + " btn";


        });
```

Comment: But why? If you're adding another class to all elements with a specific class, why not just add the same behaviours to the original element-class (assuming it's for a jQuery/JavaScript behaviour), or extend/amend the style rules in the stylesheet (if it's for styling/presentation of the elements)? The question you ask is easy enough, but it seems that there's an underlying problem that might have a better solution.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since it appears you are using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PfKZt/)**</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.buttonSubmit').addClass('btn'); 
});
```

Without jQuery:

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PfKZt/3)**</kbd>

```
window.onload = function() {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("buttonSubmit"),
        len = buttons !== null ? buttons.length : 0,
        i = 0;
    for(i; i < len; i++) {
        buttons[i].className += " btn"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: In ES6, this works: 
```[ ...document.getElementsByClassName("buttonSubmit") ].forEach( x => x.className += ' btn' )```

Comment: ... or alternatively, using classList and querySelectorAll: ```document.querySelectorAll('.buttonSubmit').forEach(x=>x.classList.add('hidden'))```