# HTML form rendering in acf-field-functions.php

Tags: php, class, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

Within the this file of the Advanced Custom Fields (pro) plugin:

**advanced-custom-fields-pro/includes/acf-field-functions.php**

on rows 733 - 751 the fields HTML is rendered:

```
    // Render HTML
    echo "<$element $attributes_html>" . "\n";
        if( $element !== 'td' ) {
            echo "<$inner_element class=\"acf-label\">" . "\n";
                acf_render_field_label( $field );
                if( $instruction == 'label' ) {
                    acf_render_field_instructions( $field );
                }
            echo "</$inner_element>" . "\n";
        }
        echo "<$inner_element class=\"acf-input\">" . "\n";
            acf_render_field( $field );
            if( $instruction == 'field' ) {
                acf_render_field_instructions( $field );
            }
        echo "</$inner_element>" . "\n";
    echo "</$element>" . "\n";
```

Is it possible to change the class `acf-label` to `uk-form-label` and the class `acf-input` to `uk-form-controls`?

Maybe adding some code to my functions.php or maybe a code to replace the whole file or something?

I really really need this change to implement the UIKIT frontend framework...

Fingeres crossed....

**PS. Or is there a way to completely overwrite the following function:**

`function acf_render_field_wrap( $field, $element = 'div', $instruction = 'label' ) {`

Comment: Your best bet is probably https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-prepare_field/ I am pretty sure the `$field` array passed into this has a `class` entry you should be able to overwrite at this point.

Comment: or to use Javascript to add the class to all `acf-label`

Comment: like so : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18294771/4244684'